# Pusher Notification received by sender and working in Chrome only. Laravel 5.4 and JQuery

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am using Pusher API for sending notifications in Laravel 5.4 with JQuery. I found out that whenever I send notification from Firefox or Safari...it reaches chrome browser successfully but not vice versa. Another problem is that when I send message, it is being received by me!!! Although I used `toOthers()` method

My Code is below. Please let me know if you need more info.

**Controller Code**

```
broadcast(new SendMessageEvent("hi", \Auth::user()))->toOthers();
```

**Blade**

```
$(function() {
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher('Pusher API key', {
        authEndpoint: 'broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}}
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user-channel.{!! \Auth::user()->UserID !!}');
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\SendMessageEvent', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**Event**

```
class SendMessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $msg;
    public $user;
    public $userid;

    public function __construct($msg, $user) {
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->userid = $this->user->UserID;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user-channel.1');
    }
}
```

**Channel**

```
Broadcast::channel('user-channel.{userid}', function ($user, $userid) {
    return (int) $user->UserID === (int) $userid;
});
```

Comment: From the documentation: “In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.” More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Comment: i think on your `SendMessageEvent` class method `broadcastOn`, you need to change it like this: `return new PrivateChannel('user-channel.'.$this->userid);`

Comment: question still open?

Comment: Yes me too. I can send notification from firefox to chrome (chrome catch the push notification) but not chrome to firefox (can't catch it) .

Comment: can i ask why are you send sending notification through controller?

Answer (score 1):

I found this while searching, if the question is still open :

your event broadcasts everything to userID 1

```
 return new PrivateChannel('user-channel.1');
```

but your other users connect to their own channel with their own userID. Change to public channel and test again with your code, the rest seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use Laravel Echo, which works better than raw pusher, and works with private channels and whatever push notification you got from Laravel :

```js
    Echo.private('{{'App.User.'.Auth::id()}}')
                    .listen('.notify', (e) => {
                        ...
                    })                  
                .notification((notification) => {
                    ...
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about other browser but I know `toOthers()` issue (For VueJs)

If you are using Vue and Axios, the socket ID will automatically be attached to every outgoing request as a `X-Socket-ID` header. Then, when you call the `toOthers` method [Only to others](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#only-to-others)

If you want to set `X-Socket-ID` manually [Set request header](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/61)